# How to inject my own video frames in the android camera to test apps

Tags: testing, video, camera, appium, inject

I want to inject a video when testing apps with camera. I'm using appium and there is no connection to camera for android phones.

There should be a video shared by me and when camera turn on and ready to test i wanna inject my video.

Comment: This is not a real programming question (off-topic for this forum). Ask at [Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/) forum using your same account. **PS:** If still failing then maybe try using an emulator on your desktop. If on Windows PC then you can first install OBS (a streaming app with a virtual webcam which allows video files as it input). Once installed, other apps will see its "virtual camera" as a camera device. Your APK running on the emulator should pick it up (then you load the file inside OBS to see it on the APK camera view)... One possible thing to try.